# The length of an arrow in the Bloch sphere

Tags: python-3.x, quantum-computing

I'm trying to build something called bloch sphere. This represents a state of a quantum bits in the form of an arrow in a sphere, whose radius is 1.0.

I wrote the codes below.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, combinations

print("Put angle theta and phi, 0≤theta≤180, 0≤phi≤360")
theta = input("theta:")
phi = input("phi:")
theta = float(theta)
phi = float(phi)
X = np.sin(phi)
Y = np.sin(theta)
Z = np.cos(theta)

class quantum_gates:
def __init__(self,X,Y,Z):
    self.X = float(X)
    self.Y = float(Y)
    self.Z = float(Z)

    if theta <0 or theta >180 or phi < 0 or phi >360:
        print("Put the value of angles again")
    else:
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
        ax.set_aspect("equal")
        u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 0:np.pi:10j]
        x = np.cos(u)*np.sin(v)
        y = np.sin(u)*np.sin(v)
        z = np.cos(v)
        ax.set_xlabel('y')
        ax.set_ylabel('x')
        ax.set_zlabel('z')
        ax.plot_wireframe(y, x, z, color="black")
        ax.quiver(0,0,0,Y,X,Z,color="red",length=1.0)
```

When I put (theta, phi) = (30,0), the tip of the arrow reaches the surface of the sphere.  However, when I put (theta,phi) = (30,30), the tip of the arrow goes outside of the sphere.

You can see the image of the current situation from the link below.

[image: An arrow tip reaching outside of the sphere]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you perform transformation between coordinates in a wrong way. `X`, `Y`, and `Z` should be calculated as follows ([wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations#From_spherical_coordinates)):

```
X = np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
Y = np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)
Z = np.cos(theta)
```

Also, numpy trigonometric functions accept values in radians. So, theta should be in the range [0, pi], phi should be in the range [0, 2 * pi). To convert degrees to radians you may use `numpy.radians()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question.  I just realized that I should have used radian, but I didn't know the correct way to calculate X,Y,Z.